# f.lux lost effectiveness after setting temperature on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, f.lux

I installed f.lux via `apt-get` and replaced `xflux` in `/usr/bin` with the daemon for X-window (32-bit build with support for multiple monitors). I launched it, set my location and chose my favourite colour temperature (4200 K) and clicked `Preview`.

So far everything was fine, both my laptop and external monitor began to turn 'warm'. But after a second it lost efficiency and came back to '6500 K'. How to fix this problem?